# custom browse by

Tags: categories, tags, archives, dropdown

I am trying to create my own simple sidebar to display the following:

```
browse by archives (monthly) - it works
brows by categories (only main, no subcategories) does not work, misisng ref link.
browse by tag (all tags with links). does not work. Could someone look at the code and let me know what i do wrong.
```

I try to use the same select - option dropdown structure for all above. code below. Thank you for help

```
<div class="tag-archive" style="margin: 20px 0;"> 
    <select class="" name="archive-dropdown"  onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Wybierz Miesiąc')); ?></option>  
        <?php wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1)); ?>
    </select>                
</div>


<div class="tag-category" style="margin: 20px 0;">  
    <?php
    echo '<select name="categories">';
    // Add custom option as default
    echo '<option>' . __('Select categories', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
    // Get categories as array
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'show_count' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
        // Check if current term ID is equal to term ID stored in database
        $selected = ( $stored_category_id == $category->term_id ) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $category->name . '</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
    ?>

<div class="tag-cloud" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <?php
        echo '<select class="tags">';
        // Add custom option as default
        echo '<option>' . __('Select Tag', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
        // Get categories as array
        $tags = get_tags(array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC'));
        foreach ((array) $tags as $tag){
        // Check if current term ID is equal to term ID stored in database
            $selected = ($tag == $tag->term_id ) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="<a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel = "tag">' . $tag->name . '(' . $tag->count . ')'.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>                  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tag code you are missing a few quotes chars, the `$tag` var, and you cant `endforeach` like that i add braces for it:

```
<div class="tag-cloud" style="margin: 20px 0;">
        <?php
        echo '<select class="tags">';
        // Add custom option as default
        echo '<option>' . __('Select Tag', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
        // Get categories as array
        $tags = get_tags(array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC'));
        foreach ((array) $tags as $tag){
        // Check if current term ID is equal to term ID stored in database
            $selected = ($tag == $tag->term_id ) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="<a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel = "tag">' . $tag->name . '(' . $tag->count . ')'.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>                  
    </div>
```